# cannot use any protocol besides SSLv23 in python2 ssl wrapper with self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, python-2.x

I generated my self-signed certificate with open ssl

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout cert.pem
```

I am using python2, and this is my server code:

```
import socket, ssl 

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('localhost', 10023))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                 server_side=True,
                                 certfile="cert.pem",
                                 ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    try:
        data = connstream.read()
        print data
    finally:
        connstream.write('hi this is server')
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()
```

this code works well, my client can get 'hi this is server' successfully. however, when i changed the `ssl_version` from ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23 to ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1 or ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3, there will be an error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

if i changed ssl_versiton to ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv2:

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1406B0CB:SSL routines:GET_CLIENT_MASTER_KEY:peer error no cipher
```

this is my client code, I hope this may help to generate the issue:

```
import socket, ssl 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
                           ca_certs="cert.pem",
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
ssl_sock.connect(('localhost', 10023))
ssl_sock.write('hi this is client')
data = ssl_sock.read()
print data
ssl_sock.close()
```

I can not understand what's wrong with these. how could I use protocols other than SSLv23?

Comment: It depends on what SSL protocol(s) the peer is configured to accept, as well as on the local configuration.

Comment: Late but: you didn't specify client ssl_version so it defaulted to SSLv23 and in 2012 you were likely using OpenSSL 0.9.8 where SSLv23 client sends SSLv2 *format* ClientHello requesting negotiation up to SSLv3 or TLSv1. OpenSSL server SSLv23 accepts this format and negotiates up, but specific protocol SSLv3 or TLSv1 (and in OpenSSL 1.0.1 up also TLSv1_1 or TLSv1_2) does not accept old format. Server protocol SSLv2 does accept the old format hello but here it found no usable (shared) cipher; I'm not sure why. In any case SSLv2 has been broken since last century so don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered that the keyfile is needed for server side while certfile is not for client side?

Slightly modified your code here, hope it could help.

```
#Server side:
import socket, ssl 

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('localhost', 10023))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                    keyfile='key.pem',
                                 server_side=True,
                                 certfile="cert.crt",
                                 ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    try:
        data = connstream.read()
        print data
    finally:
        connstream.write('hi this is server')
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()


#Client side:
import socket, ssl 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
                           ca_certs="cert.crt",
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
                           )
ssl_sock.connect(('localhost', 10023))
ssl_sock.write('hi this is client')
data = ssl_sock.read()
print data`enter code here`
ssl_sock.close()
```

Comment: The `openssl req` shown in the Q puts both the privatekey _and_ the selfsigned cert in the single file `cert.pem`, so that single file is sufficient for the server; see the doc. The client will ignore the key and use only the cert so it's okay also.